# Does this solution of a function give us only real or also imaginary solutions?

Tags: stability-in-odes, bifurcation

I am solving the following function  for stability

$\dot x=x(x^2-1-\kappa)$

The linearisation of the function at rest position $x_1= \sqrt{1+\kappa}$ gives us the form $\frac{df}{dx}(x_1)= 3\,\sqrt{1+\kappa}^2-1-\kappa$.

Now the question is:

Will this solution be real or would it also include imaginary numbers for the case of $\kappa>-1$. Should I square the roots and then get only real values? or keep as it is?

Answer (score 2):

If $\kappa > -1$ then $f(x)= x(x^2-(1+ \kappa))$ has three distinct zeros $0, \pm \sqrt{1+\kappa}$ and you can check that $f'(0) <0$ and $f'(\pm \sqrt{1+\kappa} )>0$
hence $0$ is stable and the other two are not.

If $\kappa <-1$ then $f$ has one zero at $x=0$ and $f'(0) >0$ so is unstable.

If $\kappa = -1$ then $f$ has one zero at $x=0$ but $f'(0) = 0$ so the linearisation is not conclusive. (It is not hard to show that $x=0$ is unstable, but it does not follow from lineaarisation.)

Under the assumption that you are dealing with a real system, you only care about the real equilibrium points, that is, the real zeros of $f$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am interested in knowing if there is an imaginary part to the solution in order to know type of Bifurcation that shows up. In your case, you considered only the real part of the solution. Is there an imaginary part, or simply not? Thank you.

Comment: Does your equation have non real initial conditions?

Comment: no it doesnt. but im wondering if I should keep the square root as it is in the linearization or cross it out with the power of 2. If I keep it there will be an imaginary part of the eigenvalues.

Comment: The original equation can be extended in the obvious way to the complex plane and will have imaginary non real in the case $\kappa <-1$. My familiarity is with real systems, so if I had to evaluate stability at these points I would look at the eigenvalues of the real $2 \times 2$ system $\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$ where $f'(z_0) = a+ib$ at an equlibrium $z_0$.

Comment: If you are dealing with a purely real system (as in only real initial conditions) then the non real solutions are of no concern.

Comment: You will only need to linearise at an equlibrium, and since these are all real, the issue of square root is irrelevant. If $\kappa <-1 $ the only real equilibrium is $x=0$.